# create several OkHttp3 clients with same connection pool

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

I am using Retrofit2.
Can i create several OkHttp3 clients and share the connection pool from first instance with the others? is it thread safe and good practice?

Answer (score 7):

Instantiate your `ConnectionPool` and use `OkHttpClient.Builder` of each client and pass all new client instances with `connectionPool(ConnectionPool connectionPool)` method.

`ConnectionPool` is only used to reuse the connection and it is thread safe safe. However you should consider this snippet from the readme of OkHttp:

> There is no longer a global singleton connection pool. In OkHttp 2.x,
>   all OkHttpClient instances shared a common connection pool by default.
>   In OkHttp 3.x, each new OkHttpClient gets its own private connection
>   pool. Applications should avoid creating many connection pools as
>   doing so prevents connection reuse. Each connection pool holds its own
>   set of connections alive so applications that have many pools also
>   risk exhausting memory!

Comment: I can also use the newBuilder method which copies the connectionPool of the first istance to the second.
The question is whether execution of requests from different threads will be thread safe and considered a good practice when using retrofit2